# How to write nosetests for f2py bindings

Tags: python, nose, f2py

So I've put together some Python bindings to some legacy Fortran code. They work, I can install this with the usual `python setup.py install`, but I would like to write some nosetests to check things using e.g. `travis-ci`.

I'm not sure how one goes about doing this. If one installs the package, and the bindings are available, then obviously you can just import the different methods and classes and use them in tests, but what if the package isn't installed? I guess that a pointer to some examples would be worthwile.